# Data Written in One Excel Column Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi i am new to writing data to excel however after doing much research and reading documentation I have done it.

My Problem:
When string data is stored in my array and written it to excel however it does not put it in one column (which is what I want) it spaces each string out in a column to the right of it in a diagonal descent in my spread sheet. A picture is below.

[image]

What I want is for each string/name to be put in one column under each other. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
    System.out.println("Write data to an Excel Sheet");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/hoflerj/Desktop/text2excel/finish.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("clientid");
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) i);
    cell = row.createCell(i);
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    cell.setCellValue(arr.get(i).toString());
    }


    System.out.println("Done");
    workBook.write(out);
    arr.clear();
    out.close();
```

Comment: You probably don't need that for loop.  Check out this website (https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/) and hopefully this can help.

Comment: I will check out that site however. I don't see how I would write the data stored in the array to the excel document without using a loop.

Comment: What I am trying to do is keep it all in one column which each name stacked under the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are increasing column index as well.
Just change from:

```
cell = row.createCell(i);
```

To:

```
cell = row.createCell(0);
```

So the **`For Loop`** will be like:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
    row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) i);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    cell.setCellValue(arr.get(i).toString());
}
```

Or with fewer lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
    row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) i);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue( arr.get(i).toString() );
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Okay will try this.

Comment: Glad to help :)